# How to clone screen of my Android phone to a Fire tablet

Tags: screen-mirroring

I wish to use a Fire 8 HD tablet as a "repeater" to view what's shown on the screen of my Android phone, specifically for in-car navigation w/ Google Maps & Waze, connecting between them with Bluetooth.

I've downloaded TeamViewer on both the phone and tablet, but am not able to connect the two.

How can I do this with an app other than TeamViewer which uses Bluetooth?

Once I connect the two, how do I keep the Fire tablet from timing out & going dark?

Comment: Does TeamViewer support data transmission in a local network? I would prefer a pure local solution like screen cast (you phone should have a built-in screen cast sender in quick menu). And on the tablet you can try one of the screen cast receiver apps. You just need to make sure both devices are within the same Wifi network and device-to-device communication is allowed in this Wifi.